# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm getting this error...

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '1' in C:\path-to-plugin.php on line 147

When I run the keyword "Test $2/1 test+word!" through the function below

```
function my_get_kw_in_content($theKeyword, $theContent)
    {
//ERROR OCCURS NEXT LINE
    return preg_match('/\b' . $theKeyword . '\b/i', $theContent);
    }
```

I'm assuming that I need to sanitize the keyword to escape the "/" character (and possibly more). I'd appreciate any suggestions you have to sanitize the string before running it through the preg_match.

UPDATE:
This appears to work thanks to Thai:

```
function my_get_kw_in_content($theKeyword, $theContent)
    {
    $theKeyword = preg_quote($theKeyword, '/');
    return preg_match('/\b' . $theKeyword . '\b/i', $theContent);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to quote regular expression characters.

Like this:

```
preg_quote($theKeyword, '/');
```

Where `'/'` is the delimiter in your regular expression.

Comment: Thai, I've updated my question with your answer. It appears to be working for me. Can you check my update to insure I'm implementing your answer properly?